# GoLang force computation at at run-time, rather than compile-time

Tags: go, architecture, 32bit-64bit

I am working on a project which should be available as either 64bit or 32bit.

Due to 3rd party driver, I am forced to work with int, rather than int64.

```
const (
    _   = iota // ignore zero iota
    KiB = 1 << (10 * iota)
    MiB
    GiB
    TiB
)

func doSomething() (ok bool) {
    if strconv.IntSize != 64 {
        // exiting early from function because default int is not 64bit.

        return false
    }

    ThirdPartyDriverBytes = 5 * GiB

    return true
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler complains, I get a `constant 5368709120 overflows int` error.

How can I effectively work around this issue? Is there a way I can force this 5 * GiB calculation to occur at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly type the variable to `int64` instead of the platform-dependent `int`:

```
var ThirdPartyDriverBytes int64
const (
    _  int64 = iota // ignore zero iota
    KiB = 1 << (10 * iota)
    MiB
    GiB
    TiB
)
```

This is clearer than trying to work around the compiler inferring types from constant expressions.

Comment: `ThirdPartyDriverBytes` is of type `int`. Which means that will not compile on 32bit

Comment: Which is why I'm saying it should be declared explicitly to be an `int64`. If you need 64 bits of capacity, you should explicitly declare a 64-bit type, rather than letting the compiler pick a size (and potentially pick one too small to hold the values you need).

Comment: _int64 is supported on 32-bit platforms.
The generated code is more than the single
instruction it would be on a 64-bit platform
but is reasonably efficient.  It's the same thing
that C compilers do to support long long (64-bit)
on 32-bit platforms.
Russ_ [reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/mtnn-01Dh_I)

Comment: Without maintaining a fork of the 3rd party lib or potentially setups for other users if the lib updates to use int64, this is simply not possible. `if strconv.IntSize != 64 {` that's why im asserting int is 64 bit before running. unless I am missing something? see issue raised in lib here: https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues/512

Comment: Now given that I am forced to use `int` by the driver, not `int64` I don't see how the above soln solves the problem.

Comment: If you're forced to use `int`, and you need to support 32 bit platforms, and you need to store integers that overflow `int32`... Then there is no solution. One of those things has to budge.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a workaround... `5 * GiB` is a constant expression, so gets computed by the compiler.

By splitting up into multiple statements, it no longer happens.

```
defaultBytes := 5
ThirdPartyDriverBytes = defaultBytes * GiB
```